# This class is not a key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I know this question has been asked many times, but all of the situations seem to be different then mine and I do not have the ability to comment.

I am trying to learn how to make a UserDefault variable, but it keeps crashing. The error I am getting in the logs is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
    reason: '[<NSUserDefaults 0x1097d6bf8> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is 
    not key value coding-compliant for the key AmountOfCoins.'
```

Here is all the times the UserDefault was used in my code:

```
    class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var CoinCount = Int()
```

^Here I defined a variable to make accessing the coin count easier.

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    if let x = UserDefaults.value(forKey: "AmountOfCoins") as? Int{
        CoinCount = x
    }
```

^ This was used to check if the AmountOfCoins was empty. I think I may have made a mistake here.

```
   func startGame() {
    score = 0
    CoinCount = UserDefaults.value(forKey: "AmountOfCoins") as! Int
    scoreview.text = "\(score)"
    coinview.text = "\(UserDefaults.value(forKey: "AmountOfCoins"))"
}
```

^ Here is a function that is called when the game is started

```
        func addCoin(){
    run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Coin.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
    CoinCount += 1
    UserDefaults.standard.set(CoinCount, forKey: "AmountOfCoins")
    scoreview.text = "\(UserDefaults.value(forKey: "AmountOfCoins"))"
    coinview.text = "\(CoinCount)"
```

^ And lastly here is a function that is called whenever a coin needs to be added.

I have read a few different methods for fixing this error but I really don't understand how exactly it works.

Comment: Use `integer(forKey:)` instead of `value(forKey:)` to retrieve the value.

Comment: should be `UserDefaults.standard` and it has a method called `integer(forKey:)` and it doesn't return an optional

Comment: @JAL When I use UserDefaults.interger it asks me to add (UserDefaults) rather then  (forKey: )

Comment: to load it `coinCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "AmountOfCoins")`

Comment: BTW It is Swift convention to name your vars starting with a lowercase letter. Change `CoinCount` to `coinCount`

Comment: and to save it `UserDefaults.standard.set(coinCount, forKey: "AmountOfCoins")`

Answer (score 13):

As people have said in the comments above, it should be something like this

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.value(forKey: "AmountOfCoins")
```

instead of

```
UserDefaults.value(forKey: "AmountOfCoins")
```

Comment: It's UserDefault.standard.Integer(forKey: ). Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add .standard

Like UserDefaults.standard.value

You don't necessarily have to create a UserDefaults object